# Looking for more efficient way to select max RowUpdateDateTime column across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops

Each row in each table of my database has a RowUpdateDateTime column, which is the latest time that particular row was updated or inserted.  I've also got between 1 and 7 distinct sources of data coming into each table; some have 1, some have 7.

Basically, I'm trying to loop through these tables and find the most recent RowUpdateDateTime for each of these sources, where applicable, for each of these tables.  Here's the really long query that I and a colleague wrote to do this.  It's functional, but I suspect could be re-written.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SourceID') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #SourceID
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tables') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Tables
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UpdateCount') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #UpdateCount
END

GO


CREATE TABLE #SourceID
    (
    SourceID varchar(4),
    CounterID int
    )

INSERT INTO #SourceID (SourceID,CounterID)
SELECT 'ZEND',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF',3
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'GHI',4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKL',5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MNO',6
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PQR',7
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STU',8

GO  

CREATE TABLE #Tables
    (
    Name varchar(100),
    CounterID int
    )

INSERT INTO #Tables (Name,CounterID)
SELECT 'livendb..Table1',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table2',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table3',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table4',4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table5',5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table6',6
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livendb..Table7',7
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table8',8
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table9',9
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table10',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table11',11
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table12',12
UNION ALL
SELECT 'livefdb..Table13',13

GO

Declare @counter varchar(10)
Declare @tablename varchar(100)
Declare @query varchar(1100)
Declare @sourceid varchar(4)
Declare @sourcecounter varchar(10) 


CREATE TABLE #UpdateCount
    (
    SourceID varchar(3),
    TableName Varchar(100),
    MaxRowUpdateDateTime datetime,
    --TotalRowCount int
    )


SET @sourcecounter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SourceID)
SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM #Tables)

WHILE @sourcecounter >= 0
BEGIN
    SET @sourceid = (SELECT SourceID FROM #SourceID WHERE CounterID = (@sourcecounter))
        IF @sourceid <> 'ZEND'
        BEGIN
                WHILE @counter >=0
                BEGIN
                    SET @tablename = (SELECT Name FROM #Tables WHERE CounterID = (@counter))

                    IF @counter <> 0
                    BEGIN
                    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO #UpdateCount (SourceID,TableName,MaxRowUpdateDateTime)
                                VALUES (
                                        (SELECT SourceID FROM #SourceID WHERE CounterID = '+@sourcecounter+')
                                        ,(SELECT Name FROM #Tables WHERE CounterID = '+@counter+')
                                        ,(SELECT MAX(RowUpdateDateTime) FROM '+@tablename+' WHERE SourceID = 
                                                        (SELECT SourceID FROM #SourceID WHERE CounterID = '+@sourcecounter+')))'

                    EXECUTE (@query)
                    END
                SET @counter = (@counter-1)
                END

        END

    SET @sourcecounter = (@sourcecounter-1)
    SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM #Tables)
END

        SELECT  SourceID
                ,SUBSTRING(TableName,10,22) as TableName
                ,MaxRowUpdateDateTime
                --,TotalRowCount
        FROM #UpdateCount 
            Where MaxRowUpdateDateTime IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY TableName

DROP TABLE #Tables
DROP TABLE #UpdateCount
DROP TABLE #SourceID
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off (as the code is simpler) following a pattern like this example. It does not answer your entire question (its quite hard to code dynamic SQL with no data - for me at least).

This should give you a good starting point to work from.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX) =''

;WITH Tables AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME = '[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + ']' + '.' + '[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ModifiedDate'
)
SELECT  @Query  = @Query + 
'   SELECT   SourceTable    = '''+ TABLE_NAME + '''
            ,RecentMod      = MAX(ModifiedDate) 
    FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL'
FROM Tables

SET @Query = LEFT(@Query, LEN(@Query) - LEN(' UNION ALL'))

EXEC (@Query)
```

Producing a result like this;

```
SourceTable                                     |   RecentMod
===========================================================================
[dbo].[AWBuildVersion]                          |   2012-03-14 00:00:00.000
[dbo].[OLE DB Destination]                      |   2008-07-31 00:00:00.000
[HumanResources].[Department]                   |   2002-06-01 00:00:00.000
[HumanResources].[Employee]                     |   2009-01-26 09:17:08.637
[HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]    |   2007-12-15 00:00:00.000
[HumanResources].[EmployeePayHistory]           |   2008-07-31 00:00:00.000
[HumanResources].[JobCandidate]                 |   2008-01-23 18:32:21.313
[HumanResources].[Shift]                        |   2002-06-01 00:00:00.000
[HumanResources].[vJobCandidate]                |   2008-01-23 18:32:21.313
[Person].[Address]                              |   2008-07-31 00:00:00.000
[Person].[AddressType]                          |   2002-06-01 00:00:00.000
[Person].[BusinessEntity]                       |   2012-01-14 13:47:22.467
[Person].[BusinessEntityAddress]                |   2008-10-13 11:15:06.967
...
```

Comment: That looks like it pulls the last time the table structure was changed.  I'm looking for the last time each of those tables had a row inserted into them.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, you have a `RowUpdateDateTime` column you said. Use that field :) The posted code is merely an example.